# Syntax errors in the verilog code

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, hdl

I want to convert this c code to verilog module but I am having some difficulty

```
void window_averaging(void) {

  register unsigned int i, k;
  for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    // Copying first 128 output samples to the Window 0 and so on till Window 7.
    W[count][i] = O[i];
  }


  for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k< 8; k++) {
      O[i] += W[k][i];
    }
    O[i] /= 8; // Averaging over 8 window
  } 
  count = (count++)%8; // Count = 0  after all the window elements are filled.
}
```

Verilog:

```
module window_averaging(
  input      [16:0]in_noise, //input from noise cancellation
  input            clk,
  output reg [16:0]window_average // output after window averaging
  );

integer i;
integer k;
integer count = 0;
reg [16:0] store_elements[0:7][0:128]; //  2-D array for window averaging
reg [16:0] temp;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
  //  Copying first 128 output samples to the Window 0 and so on till Window 7
  for(i=0 ; i < 128 ; i = 1+1)
  begin
    store_elements[count][i] = in_noise;
  end
  for(i=0; i<128 ; i=i+1)
  begin
    for(k=0;k<8;k = k+1)
    begin
      temp = temp + store_elements[i][k];
    end
    window_average = temp/8;
    count = (count+1)%8;
  end
end
endmodule
```

The errors I am getting are syntax error near "(" and "=". I am little new to verilog can anyone help me how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

First you are trying to drive a wire from inside an @always block which is not allowed. If you convert the wires to regs then it will work:

```
    module window_averaging(
    input [16:0]in_noise, //input from noise cancellation
    input clk,
    output reg [16:0]window_average // output after window averaging
    );

    integer i;
    integer k;
    integer count = 0;
    reg [16:0] store_elements[0:7][0:128]; //  2-D array for window averaging
    reg [16:0] temp;
    ...
```

Also I believe to be consistent with your C code the line count = (count+1)%8; should be outside the for loop like so:

```
    window_average = temp/8;
    end
    count = (count+1)%8;
    end
    endmodule
```

Comment: thanks for your reply I did that and error was gone , but when am doing simulation for the code the output value I am getting is a unknown value (X).

Comment: As Remian8985 says you also have two more mistakes. When you fix these does it work? In your simulation are you setting in_noise to some sensible values (not 'X')?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are using to compile, but I think the following stuff should give you errors: 
For the first loop:

```
for(i=0 ; i < 128 ; i = 1+1)
```

change to `i= i+1`

Also, in line:

```
temp = temp + store_elements[i][k];
```

remember the declaration `store_elements[0:7][0:128]` , so may be switch `i` and `k` ?

This isn't an answer really. Sorry, I don't have comment privilege yet.